# Installing dlib in Python

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, dlib, face

I want to install `face_recognition` for a project that I am about to start. However, `face_recognition` has a dependency on `dlib` and I don't know how to install that.

I entered `pip install dlib`, however, an error was thrown since it said that I needed to install CMake. Here is the error:

```
  Using cached dlib-19.24.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: dlib
  DEPRECATION: dlib is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for dlib did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dlib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Thus, I tried to install CMake:

```
Collecting CMake
  Using cached cmake-3.25.0-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (32.6 MB)
Installing collected packages: CMake
  WARNING: The scripts cmake.exe, cpack.exe and ctest.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\Emma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed CMake-3.25.0
```

However, when I tried to install `dlib` again, I got the same error even though I installed CMake successfully.

How could I install dlib now? For reference, I am using a Windows 10 or 11 system, and Python 3.11 64-bit.

Comment: This is your main problem: "*WARNING: **The scripts cmake.exe**, cpack.exe and ctest.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\Emma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\Scripts' which **is not on PATH**.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update/Install Visual C++

Maybe try installing/updating Visual C++. Because this is necessary for `CMake` to run. You can install it from here, https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15#

## Installation with Wheel File

Run this:

`pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f`

## Installation from Internet

1. Install CMake from https://cmake.org/download/
2. Run this,
   `set PATH="%PATH%;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin`
   to add CMake to your path. You can also do this manually by Editing The Environment Variables.
   3)Download the following,
   https://pypi.org/project/dlib/#files.
3. In the specified folder in which you extracted the install files run the following,
   `python setup.py install`.